# error in npm start while running AGCloud Project in windows

Tags: reactjs, apache-age, agens-graph

I'm trying to run the AGCloud [project](https://github.com/AGEDB-INC/Cloud-Express) on windows 10. the project is built with React JS.

I cloned the main branch of the repository in my system, and then installed dependencies in both front-end and back-end using `npm i` command and then moved to the root directory.

and then I executed the following command:

> `npm start`

I was expecting that the project will be compiled successfully

but I encountered the following error:

[image: image showing error]

this is error in the front-end.

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because there are 3 different package.json files, and you haven't run `npm i` in the root directory.

The quicker way to do this could be that run `npm run setup`
You can check package.json file that's located in the root directory, there `setup` command automatically cd into each directory to install node modules,
Then run `npm run start` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can verify if everything is OK in the packages running:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Answer (score 0):

First run "npm install".

It installs all the required dependencies used by the project on your system.

Then run "npm start".

If it doesn't work, try "npm run dev".

Also make sure to use the right configurations for the project.

Answer (score 0):

If the AGCloud project fails to compile you should check Node.js and npm versions alongside verifying dependencies and upgrade or fix dependencies with vulnerabilities and install the stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you have the correct version of **npm** required for the installation of **AGE Viewer**.

Finally, you have to be in the AGE Viewer directory to run the commands associated with installation and starting up AGE Viewer i.e you should run `npm run start` in the AGE Viewer directory not the root directory.

Kindly revisit the [docs](https://github.com/apache/age-viewer) for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have the correct version of npm installed. Also check if all the dependencies have been installed.

You can refer to this guide: [Age-viewer](https://github.com/apache/age-viewer/blob/main/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand is there is an error in Node or NPM versions. Firstly you can check that the versions you have installed are compatible with the project by using these commands:

```
    node -v 
    npm -v
```

These will display the versions that you have installed on your local machine in the terminal.

If the versions are incompatible you can uninstall them and reinstall by running `npm install`

Finally, if the issue persists you can try cleaning the cache by using

`npm cache clean --force` and use `npm install` right after. This should help.

If these steps don't help do try consulting the project documentation for your particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

First Run the following command to remove all the data present in the cache folder.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then run the following command to install all the required dependencies.

```
npm install
```

Also make sure that the node version that you have is 14.6 to be compatible with AGE-Viewer because this was mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/age-viewer/blob/main/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the answers above and it still isn't working then try the following:

```
# linux
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
# windows
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

You need to run this in your terminal before running the project and also do a fresh install of the packages before rerunning it.